# codeigniter curl error

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I was trying out this piece of code and keep on getting this error
      function create(){

```
    $post = array();

    //get all the data from the form into an array
    $post = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'abbrev' => $this->input->post('abbrev'),           
                'long_name' => $this->input->post('long_name'),
                'long_abbrev' => $this->input->post('long_abbrev'),
                'url' => $this->input->post('url'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description')
                );  


    //encode the data and set it as output to push to api
    $json_data=json_encode($post);
    $this->curl->post('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges', $json_data);
```

And this is the error i get

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Colleges::$curl

Filename: controllers/colleges.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $this->curl->post('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges', $json_data);
```

to

```
 $this->load->library('curl');
 $this->curl->post('http://localhost:8888/api/colleges', $json_data);
```